# Nginx screen appering on first request to the domain

Tags: node.js, api, http, nginx, proxy

The first requests in the browser to this following API's are appering the Nginx screen. 
[Goeat Api](http://goeat.lauradeveloper.com.br/) [GympointApi](http://gympoint.lauradeveloper.com.br/)

Idk what is wrong on my proxy configuration

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name gympoint.lauradeveloper.com.br;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name goeat.lauradeveloper.com.br;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        }


}
```

It's working completely fine but on the first request to the browser, shows this nginx screen. Looking my proxy configuration, does anyone know what i'm did wrong?

Comment: What happens if you try to test with curl, not browser? Whether result is the same?

Comment: Idk why but this is happening just in my computer. If i try on another environment, the nginx screen doesn't appear anymore with the first request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind solved this. I had to put these same options related to proxy on the other server config.